# Why resilience4j-kotlin metrics not working?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, resilience4j

I'm using resilience4j-kotlin CircuitBreaker and I want to show metrics.

I'm Adding this dependency. 
io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-micrometer

add this codes.

```
MeterRegistry meterRegistry = new SimpleMeterRegistry();
CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry =
  CircuitBreakerRegistry.ofDefaults();
CircuitBreaker foo = circuitBreakerRegistry
  .circuitBreaker("backendA");
CircuitBreaker boo = circuitBreakerRegistry
  .circuitBreaker("backendB");

TaggedCircuitBreakerMetrics
  .ofCircuitBreakerRegistry(circuitBreakerRegistry)
  .bindTo(meterRegistry)
```

CircuitBreaker working successful but metrics didn't show on "../actuator/metrics".
even circuit open.

Is it working on kotlin-coroutine?

Comment: Looks like you use Spring Boot and actuator. If so you should inject predefined `MeterRegistry` bean. Don't create new registry.

Comment: @AlexanderPankin
Thanks. It's working with inject bean.

Comment: Hi @reperion how did you inject bean? Could you please provide the code? I am facing a similar problem. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76654386/how-to-push-circuit-breaker-metrics-to-datadog?noredirect=1#comment135160403_76654386

Comment: @PH  try this  ```@Configuration
class CircuitBreakerConfig {
 @Autowired
 private lateinit var meterRegistry: MeterRegistry

 @Autowired
 private lateinit var circuitBreakerRegistry: CircuitBreakerRegistry

 @PostConstruct
 fun initCircuitBreakerMetrics() {
  TaggedCircuitBreakerMetrics.ofCircuitBreakerRegistry(circuitBreakerRegistry).bindTo(meterRegistry)
 }
}```