# How to push circuit breaker metrics to Datadog?

Tags: spring-boot, datadog, circuit-breaker, resilience4j, datadog-dashboard

I have configured `resilience4j-micrometer` and `spring-boot-starter-actuator` in my service. Apparently this is enough to see metrics in Datadog but I do not see the values populated for the metric for example  `resilience4j_circuitbreaker_not_permitted_calls_total` even though i see logs in my service that the circuit breaker is OPEN.

I tried to create a bean and do the following but no luck.

```
@Bean
public MeterRegistry enableCircuitBreakerMetrics() {
final CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry = CircuitBreakerRegistry.ofDefaults();
return registry -> {

            TaggedCircuitBreakerMetrics
                .ofCircuitBreakerRegistry(circuitBreakerRegistry)
                .bindTo(circuitBreakerRegistry );
        };
    }
```

Am I missing anything here? Could someone help?
I have 2 feign clients where the circuit breaker name for this is autogenerated.

Comment: How do you set up your Datadog agent?

Comment: That is set up correctly as I see other custom metrics. I have added the datadog-api-key  and added -javaagent:<path-to>/dd-java-agent.jar in the run config.

Comment: What is the Resilience4j version and Spring Boot version that you are using? Also, could you provide the spring-boot startup debug logs related to `MetricsAutoConfiguration`?

Comment: Resilience4J is 2.1.7 
and Springboot is 2.7.13

Comment: Actually, i do not see any logs related to MetricsAutoConfiguration

Comment: You can enable auto-configuration logs by setting the `debug: true` property on `application.yml` as stated  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-auto-configuration-report

Comment: Yes i just did that. I still do not see any logs related to MetricsAutoConfiguration.

Comment: Spring Boot auto-configures a composite MeterRegistry and adds a registry to the composite for each of the supported implementations that it finds on the classpath. Having a dependency on `micrometer-registry-{system}` in your runtime classpath is enough for Spring Boot to configure the registry. What kind of dep are you using? Or are you configuring the Micrometer in another way

Comment: Yeah, i had check on that. I am using micrometer-core for MeterRegistry.

Comment: It is working now :) I had to explicitly enable resilience in our project as our library sets everything by default because each metric costs.